Per-user and user group data access for AWS Amplify Gen2
I'm trying to give the following access.

Group of cognito users called 'user' to read and create
Public to read
Owner to CRUD

As per the https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/data/customize-authz/per-user-per-owner-data-access/, i've updated below
Todo: a
        .model({
            id: a.id(),
            owner: a.string()
                .authorization(allow =>(
                    [
                        allow.owner().to(['delete', 'create', 'read']),
                        allow.groups(['user']).to(['create', 'read'])
                    ]
                )),
        })
        .authorization(allow =>(
            [
                allow.publicApiKey().to(['read']),
                allow.owner(),
                allow.groups(['user']).to(['create', 'read'])
            ]
        )),

To create TODO, i used authMode as 'userPool'
client.models.Todo.create({
            ...data,
        }, {authMode: 'userPool'})

I'm logged in as user with 'user' group and i can create TODO with no issue, But when i check the owner field, it's populated with null value.
Are there anything missing on my end?
